# Setting Elevation in XML on AppCompat CardView on Android 5.0

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-cardview, android-elevation

From what I understand, early in the preview stage there seemed to be no way to set elevation in XML only on `CardView`s without a hack in Java. Now that the official release is out, is there any way of doing this in XML without writing Java code to set elevation?

I have tried `card_view:cardElevation` to no effect.  I had thought when I was using the emulators for 5.0 everything was fine. But now that I'm using the official version on my actual device all of my `CardView`s disappeared

Pre Lollipop, it works great.

Here is my full xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/cv1"
    card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
    android:layout_margin="6dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

Comment: I have gotten behind the problem but don't have an answer yet. When I upgraded to lollipop, somehow the margins or padding disappeared so they don't see the corners or the edges of the card so it is completely flat.

Answer (score 328, accepted):

It looks like a margin/padding problem, try to set the [cardUseCompatPadding](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html#attr_android.support.v7.cardview:cardUseCompatPadding) attribute to true. E.g.:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="6dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp">
```

Explanation from Android doc :

> CardView adds additional padding to draw shadows on platforms before
>   L.
>
> This may cause Cards to have different sizes between L and before L.
>   If you need to align CardView with other Views, you may need api
>   version specific dimension resources to account for the changes. As an
>   alternative, you can set cardUseCompatPadding flag to true and CardView will add the same padding values on platforms L and after.
>
> Since setting cardUseCompatPadding flag to true adds unnecessary gaps in the UI, default value is false.

Comment: card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true" got the elevation to work but added a bunch of padding also....

Comment: what is the default value of the cardElevation ?

Comment: here comes the magic  app:cardCornerRadius="3dp" thanks

Answer (score 17):

You have to use the [**`cardElevation`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html#attr_android.support.v7.cardview:cardElevation) attribute.
**Androidx libraries:**

You can use the [`MaterialCard`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/MaterialCardView.md) included in the official [Material Components library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android):

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.x.x'
```

And in your layout:

```
    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        app:cardElevation="xxdp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        ..>
```

Or the `CardView` in the androidx packages:

```
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.x.x'
```

And in your layout:

```
     <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        app:cardElevation="xxdp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        ..>
```

**OLD support library**:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    app:cardElevation="xxdp" 
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    ..>
```

Comment: No I tried again, and that did not work.  I added my full xml up top.

Comment: Works for me.  What's the default elevation?

Comment: Elevation
Card resting elevation: 2dp
Card raised elevation: 8dp
Cards have a default elevation of 2dp.
On desktop, cards can have a resting elevation of 0dp and gain an elevation of 8dp on hover.

From
https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/cards.html#cards-content-blocks

Comment: it's deprecated

Comment: @Makarand True.The design library is no longer maintained but I answered this question 5 years ago. In any case I've updated the answer with andriodx details.

Comment: `app:cardUseCompatPadding` made the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

If you have this line

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
```

in manifest application tag your shadows were not displayed. try to remove this line

or use

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

This worked for me! I hope it works for you too :)

Comment: yeah! that was the problem!! thank you so much! but not due to bitmap image which I've used for background, app gets slowed down :(

Answer (score 1):

It solved me by adding

xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

for example:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp">
```

Answer (score 0):

i am adding an app:cardElevation="8dp" attribute on card view, so it will be like :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/kmp_warna1" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

set in cardView

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="6dp"
card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp">
```