# Cardview not showing shadow along bottom

Tags: android, android-layout, android-5.0-lollipop, shadows

I have the following xml for a cardview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:padding="2dp">
<!-- A CardView that contains a TextView -->
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="0dp">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/info_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </FrameLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Which results in these shadows which have no shading on the bottom at all

[image: http://i.imgur.com/xNoIDR4.png]

But I am trying to get something like this shadow, that more nicely surrounds the whole card.

[image]

I've tried changing the elevation to no avail, and searching on this issue seems to bring up nothing but people with no shadows *at all* issues which is not my case.

How can I get the shadows right?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting Elevation in XML on AppCompat CardView on Android 5.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26997109/setting-elevation-in-xml-on-appcompat-cardview-on-android-5-0)

Comment: Thank you, this solved my issue. Strange that you have to add this tag for API v21 and *forward* though. Am I understanding that right?

Comment: It's just Android fragmentation, just stackoverflow it and move along to the next feature.

Comment: Can i show the shadow on the bottom only (one side of card view)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39123951/926568

Answer (score 123):

You need to add this xml property in your card view

> app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"

Comment: at the top, something like: `<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" ...`

Answer (score 5):

Adding `clipChildren="false"` to the parent `LinearLayout` should also work.

Answer (score 2):

set elevation using card_view:cardElevation property

Comment: As explained in my question, I had tried this, but it was not the problem. After reading MLProgrammer-CiM's comment, it turned out to be that I needed to use   `card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"`

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem until I remembered that if the parent is wrapping its content, then it will not wrap the shadow, so I gave the parent a bigger size than the child that way it will include the child and the shadow of the child

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="110dp"
android:layout_height="110dp">

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="98dp"
    android:layout_height="98dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    app:cardElevation="5dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/manhattan" />

  
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

  </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

add these lines in your cardView

```
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation to your answer.