# Adding elevation according to guidelines for a card look-like view

Tags: android, material-design

I'm using this [library](https://github.com/loopeer/CardStackView?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=3766) to get a stack of cards in my app. However, the cards appearing have no elevation at all. In the [Android Material Guidelines](https://material.io/guidelines/material-design/elevation-shadows.html#elevation-shadows-elevation-android) it is written that cards should have elevation (when clicked also). How can I achieve applying elevation for this layout on both states, clicked and released, for both android > and < 21?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26997109/setting-elevation-in-xml-on-appcompat-cardview-on-android-5-0

Comment: @AmitVaghela thank you, but I don't have a card view inside my layout. I have only a linear layout with some view inside it